# How can you extract the number of hours until a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, date-time

I have dates in a spreadsheet formatted in this format: `5/10/2017  2:00:00 PM`

There is a whole column of dates like that. Formatting shouldn't matter, but I want it in that format as this is a shared spreadsheet that needs to be easy to read. The times are also in Pacific Time since that's where the "clients" are. I am in Central Time. All the times in the spreadsheet are in Pacific Time (I manually subtract two hours before entering dates).

I've been trying to figure out how to, in a separate column, display the number of hours (and *only* hours) until that time. The dates in the columns include the date and hour, but I only want hours displayed. That way, I can use Conditional Formatting to make it display in red the date is within a certain number of hours from NOW, as there is apparently no way in Excel to use conditional formatting with dates in quantity (i.e. highlight red if within next 7 days, highlight yellow if within 7 days and 14 days, highlight green if greater than 14 days, etc...)

Someone recommended the use of this formula: `=INT(B1-A1)&" days "&TEXT(B1-A1,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins ""s"" secs""")`
but that just produces a result like this: `1 days 4 hrs 20 mins 1 secs` - obviously you can't use conditional formatting with that.

Is it possible to display the number of hours left until a time? I was able to easily display number of days but unfortunately that is not specific enough.

NOTE: I have seen examples online where the date and hour are in separate columns. The datetime must be in the same column so I can't follow those examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the dates.  Multiply by 24 hours / day.

= (yourEndDate - A3) * 24

Example:

```
A1: 5/9/2017 11:00
A2: 5/8/2017 10:00
A3: =(A1-A2) * 24

A3 shows 25.
```

Excel implements dates (and times) as days (with decimal places) starting 1 => 1/1/1900 12:00 AM.  You can calculate hours, minutes, and seconds with simple conversion formulas.

For example:  0.5 represents noon (12:00 PM)